# Using a "quick connect" terminal for IEC inlet or just soldering the wires?

Tags: ac, connector

I am using the [Schaffner FN284-10-06](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/FN284-10-06/817-1107-ND/1928687) power inlet for a project. It has "quick connect" terminals, and it seems like the [3M FDI18-250Q](http://solutions.3m.com/wps/portal/3M/en_US/EMDCI/Home/Products/ProductCatalog/~/3M-Female-Disconnects?N=5431550+3294647485&rt=rud) connector would fit them. I've never used a connector like this before, and my first instinct was to just solder wires to the terminals and put a nice bit of heatshrink wrapping on them. That said, the removable terminals certainly look convenient. Are they sturdy? Can I trust the connection and the crimped wires to stay put (assume not much vibration is expected).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using slide-on terminals (we call them by the trade name "Fast-On") is common and reliable.  The only time I've ever run into problems with when the terminals were of poor quality.  The 3M terminals that you have selected should be just fine.

Something that is important to note is that the quality of the crimp used to apply the terminal to the wire affects reliability.  3M will specify the appropriate tools that are recommended and you will think that they are expensive.  And they are.  But they will guarantee you a reliable crimp.

You can purchase generic crimp tools that are inexpensive.  Some of these will do a good job but *many* will not.

Bottom line: if you have access to the proper crimp tools, the 3M connectors you linked to will work well for you.  If you *don't* have access to good crimp tools, better to be safe and simply solder your wires to those terminals.  Insulating sleeving (heatshrink, Hellermann sleeve, etc) is usually optional.

Comment: @gcv It's not recommended to accept an answer immediately, as there is now little incentive for further discussion on the topic now that the acceptance bounty has been paid. I suggest to wait at least 24 hours before accepting an answer.

Comment: Thank you. The 3M data sheet says that the TH-440 tool should work on these terminals, and I see it available at prices ranging from [$26](http://www.zoro.com/i/G1902984) to [$86](http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/3M-Electronic-Specialty/TH-440/?qs=fltJrqpyVmV3dgldkigbWA%3D%3D). Any idea if the cheaper tools might be fakes?